# How to enable enable "Asking remember password prompt" on Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, passwords

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG4Ln.png)

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="ID" value="user">
<input type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD">
```

The tag doesn't wrap  tags.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following steps:

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Select the gear on the right side of the main toolbar and choose “Internet Options“.
3. Select the “Content” tab, then select “Settings” in the “AutoComplete” section.
4. In the “AutoComplete settings” panel, check the “Ask me before saving passwords” box and the “User names and passwords on forms” box. Like this:

   [image]
5. Select “OK“. Close and restart Internet Explorer for the changes to take effect.